# Java Code Conventions: must match pattern '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'

Tags: java, coding-style

I would like to use the following constant:

```
final String ADD = "Add text";
```

However, my CheckStyle tool tells me that 'ADD' does not match the pattern `'^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.`

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with 'ADD'? Means `'^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'` that every name has to start with a low character? Is there no other possibility?

Comment: Local variables, class fields and instance fields should be capitalized camelCase. ALL_CAPS is for static finals.

Comment: ^ means start-of-string, [a-z] means a character between a and z inclusive matched 1 time (= 1 lower case letter), [a-zA-Z0-9]* means 'zero or more characters in [a-zA-Z0-9]', and $ is end-of-string.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

This regex describes something which starts with lowercase and the remainder is composed of uppercase, lowercase, and numbers. (Examples: `aVariable`, `variable`, `aNewVariable`, `variable7`, `aNewVariable7`.)

If you want your field to be constant and static, use:

```
static final String ADD = "Add text";
```

Otherwise, use:

```
final String add = "Add text";
```

Comment: First line of the OP's question: `i would like to use the following constant`. So it's definitely a constant that's wanted. But it's good that you explain the regex. +1 for that.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg True but it may be defined within a method (though I wasn't clear on that). Good point anyway, though. ;)

Answer (score 13):

If it is a constant you want, it should also be `static`

```
static final String ADD = "Add text";
```

Constants normally use uppercase letters, but since your variable was not static, it was not interpreted as a constant.

Answer (score 1):

This Regex indicate the need for camelCase with the first letter being small and then every next word having the first letter in it as capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, turns out it was because it is expected for the Java codebase I was working on to use camel case for all variables as the naming convention. So be sure to check if your variables are named according to the regex pattern `^[a-z]([a-z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$`. In my case, I got stuck in the Python mode and had my variable named `version_regex` instead of `versionRegex`. Once I have made the needed correction the error is no longer thrown.